# Strange xml parsing behaviour

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml file using DOM parser. I have a strange parsing behaviour when trying to parse the following xml file:

```
<data-list>
    <entry>
        <meta-data>
            <meta name="HANDLE">1</meta>
        </meta-data>
        <compound>
            <name>Numeric</name>
            <entries>
                <entry>
                    <meta-data>
                        <meta name="partition">2</meta>
                        <meta name="metric-id">18948</meta>
                        <meta name="unit-code">3872</meta>
                        <meta name="unit">mmHg</meta>
                    </meta-data>
                    <compound>
                        <name>Compound-Basic-Nu-Observed-Value</name>
                        <entries>
                            <entry>
                                <meta-data>
                                    <meta name="partition">2</meta>
                                    <meta name="metric-id">18949</meta>
                                </meta-data>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>0</name>
                                    <type>float</type>
                                    <value>120.000000</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <meta-data>
                                    <meta name="partition">2</meta>
                                    <meta name="metric-id">18950</meta>
                                </meta-data>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>1</name>
                                    <type>float</type>
                                    <value>76.000000</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <meta-data>
                                    <meta name="partition">2</meta>
                                    <meta name="metric-id">18951</meta>
                                </meta-data>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>2</name>
                                    <type>float</type>
                                    <value>91.000000</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                        </entries>
                    </compound>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <compound>
                        <name>Absolute-Time-Stamp</name>
                        <entries>
                            <entry>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>century</name>
                                    <type>intu8</type>
                                    <value>20</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>year</name>
                                    <type>intu8</type>
                                    <value>14</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>month</name>
                                    <type>intu8</type>
                                    <value>2</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>day</name>
                                    <type>intu8</type>
                                    <value>6</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>hour</name>
                                    <type>intu8</type>
                                    <value>15</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>minute</name>
                                    <type>intu8</type>
                                    <value>26</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>second</name>
                                    <type>intu8</type>
                                    <value>14</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <simple>
                                    <name>sec_fractions</name>
                                    <type>intu8</type>
                                    <value>0</value>
                                </simple>
                            </entry>
                        </entries>
                    </compound>
                </entry>
            </entries>
        </compound>
    </entry>
</data-list>
```

I am trying to navigate to each element using `getChildNotes()` method. However, when I use getChildNotes() for the data-list element, I am getting 3 elements only (While I was expecting to get only one "entry" element). Could someone clarify this to me?

My parsing code:

```
Document d = parse_xml(xml);

NodeList datalists = d.getElementsByTagName("data-list");

// data list
for (int i = 0; i < datalists.getLength(); ++i) {

    Node datalist = datalists.item(i);

    NodeList entries =  datalist.getChildNodes();
    // prints out 3
        System.out.println(entries.getLength());
}
```

parse_xml():

```
public static Document parse_xml(String xml)
    {
        Document d = null;

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            d = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            d.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parser error");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("SAX exception");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO exception in xml parsing");
        }

        return d;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because  one of them is element Node and the other two are text nodes and this is because of the structure of your file. You can get one as an answer by formatting your xml as follows:

```
<data-list><entry></entry></data-list>
```

instead of:

```
<data-list>
<entry>
</entry>
</data-list>
```

output will be one only.

You can Check with the following code amendments:

```
NodeList entries =  datalist.getChildNodes();
for(int j=0;j<entries.getLength();j++)
{
System.out.println(entries.item(j).getNodeName() + 
"<<<>>>>" + entries.item(j).getNodeType());
}
```

where nodetypes can be seen in source for Node class.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out by myself too, I was almost going crazy :)